# Custom name for manifest.json

Tags: manifest, google-chrome-app

I am building an app that will exist as a chrome app and a Crosswalk app, simultaneously. Both platforms require a manifest json file. Crosswalk has the option to specify the name of it's own manifest file (e.g. `crosswalk-manifest.json`), but it still tries to use the default `manifest.json` even if I specify a custom name. This causes the build to fail, and I'm left with a white screen on my phone.

This is obviously a bug in Crosswalk, but I'm wondering if there is a way to change the name of the `manifest.json` that is used by the chrome app (e.g. `chrome-manifest.json`).

Comment: I've had similar problems with HTML5 apps that are cross compiled for different platforms. I keep my manifest files in another directory and copy them to the right place at build time using grunt.

Comment: did you try <link rel="manifest" href="your/custom/path/myManifest.json">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no way to do it.

Packages without a valid `manifest.json` at the root fail immediately.

> Every app has a JSON-formatted manifest file, **named manifest.json**, that provides important information.

Comment: Do you have a source?

Comment: [Documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest) seems to be a pretty authoritative source.

Comment: Thanks for citing. I was hoping for more of a "you definitely can't rename it", instead of, "this is the standard way".

Comment: Both Chrome for Desktop and Web Store will reject something without `manifest.json` immediately. I doubt that `cca` toolchain (assuming you use it) is different.

Comment: I started using cca until they announced that no new features will be added. It would probably make things simpler, but there's nothing I need to do that only cca could provide. I suppose I will have to fork the build process to output separate folders for each platform. Thanks for your help!

Comment: "until they announced that no new features will be added" - my turn to ask for a source.

Comment: "The Chrome Apps for Mobile Toolchain is no longer being actively developed. We intend to keep it functional, but do not intend on adding any new features." https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps/blob/master/README.md